# .Net 6 Serilog not writing logs in Docker Container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose

If I run my web API application through the Kestral server, logs are getting created but if I run the application through docker only folder is getting created and the file is not generating. Any help would be appreciated.

**Installed Package**

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
```

**Program.cs** file

```
using Serilog;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

This is my **appsettings.json** file

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/webapi-.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": "123456"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file

````
version: '3.4'

services:
  azaanwebapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi2/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "8585:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:path=/app/logs/webapi-.log
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ```
````

Comment: Have you already tried to change the log file path, so that you don't have to go one level up in the file system to create the log file ? I suspect that this can cause some troubles. What happens if, in your runtime container, you copy the compiled binaries in the root (/) of the container ? Try to change the log file path to something at the same level of the application root folder (you can simply try "logs/log.txt", without the trailing ../)

Comment: Thanks @EnricoMassone it works
But my doubt is the path I mentioned in docker-compose.yml should override appsettings.json file right? Why it's not happening?

Comment: Try replace : with __ (double under score)